# How to Reload custom section nodes Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I have custom Store section in Umbraco 4.5.2 which has list of all the stores coming from custom table.I want to reload the Store tree after updting store detail from code behind.

Thanls

Answer (score 0):

when you create xml tree nodes to bind the custom section you have to add an option to xmlTreeNode for the node to get refreshed

```
xNode.Menu.AddRange(new List<IAction> { ActionNew.Instance, ActionRefresh.Instance, ActionDelete.Instance });
```

Here `ActionRefresh.Instance` will refresh the nodes